# definition of primes for higher hyperoperations

Tags: prime-numbers, definition, hyperoperation

I was reading yesterday when I came across the history of counting. There was some evidence of an early understanding of prime numbers. I thought that I would try changing the definition of primality from something like:

`domain: Z+ except 1. P is prime if the only way to express it as A*B is P*1 for any integers A and B.`

to something like:

`domain: Z+ except 1. P is prime if the only way to express it as A^B is P^1 for any integers A and B.`

(Notice the operation change from '*' to '^'.) I am just wondering what this more general definition, replacing factors with hyper roots, is called. I have written a (hugely inefficient) Java program that raises every base A to every power B where A < P and B < P to check the primality of P. So far I have found that this 'hyperprimality' is much more common than regular primality. (Also, 4 is always 'hypercomposite': 4 = 2 ^^^...^ 2 in up-arrow notation).

So I ask you: What is this called and where can I find out more?

Comment: If I am reading your definition correctly, your "hyperprimes" are precisely those numbers which are not [perfect powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power)

Comment: The first definition implies the second.

Comment: JPLF, does this mean that as the hyperoperation 'increases', the number of 'hyperprimes' strictly increases?

Answer (score 1):

Another quick comment on your java-program: Concerning the distribution of "hyper-primes", we find that non-hyper-primes are so rare that the series of their inverses converges: $$\sum_{2\leq a^b}\frac{1}{a^b} = \sum_{a=2}^\infty \sum_{b=2}^\infty \frac{1}{a^b}=\sum_{a=2}^\infty \frac{1}{a(a-1)} = 1.$$
This gives you a measure for the density of hyper-primes in the natural numbers. Note that for "normal" prime numbers, both series diverge, meaning that there are quite a lot of both of them: $$\sum_{p \; \text{prime}}\frac{1}{p} = \infty, \sum_{p \; \text{not prime}} \frac{1}{p} = \infty$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know a name for this? I am just interested. Also, I am afraid your beautiful summation algebra is sort of wasted on me. Being in middle high school, I haven't studied this sort of mathematics. School math is so boring.

Comment: I am impressed that you have started thinking out of the  box. Good for you!

Comment: I agree, very good. And sorry for the series. They actually don't say much more than "there are rather few hyper-primes". I wish you all the best for your further investigations!

Comment: @benh I think you mean "there are rather few non-hyper-primes" :).

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick comment on your java program.... To see if you can find a $B$ so that
$$P = A^B$$
you can first check if 
$$\gcd(A,P) = A$$ If this is not true, then you can skip all the trials.

If you can quickly estimate $\log_2 P$ and $\log_2 A$, then you have an estimate on $B$. So you  do not need try all the powers.

Finally, if you know $B>B_0$ then you can quickly calculate $A^{B_0}$ very efficiently by divide and conquer algorithm. If you don't mind recursion, the code will look look like this (the code is more like C/C++ than Java

```
pow(A,B) {
  if (B ==0) return 1; 
  else {
      C=pow(A,B/2); // Integer division
      if (even(B)) return C*C;
       else return C*C*A;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't thought much about the algorithm. I don't really know _how_ to.